the process made twice, when i execute my program once
In Linux, I have just simple test code to testing process made
once or twice.
when I execute my program
program is just sleep 2seconds and print something inside for loop
sudo ./test &

the process made twice.
do u know why it made twice?


Do no paste images for text. There's only one of each, don't know why you said twice.

there are two processes sudo ./test PID : 1171219  and
./test  PID : 1171220
Isn't it?

Isn't it?  Yes there is. What exactly is your question? why it made twice? Because there are two processes, most probably one sudo and the other is shell waiting for sudo. You did not post how they were created. Is there something confusing about existence of processes? Could be more specific? Please do not post images of text, please post text as text into the question. Please post the full script, you stated that program is just sleep 2seconds and print something inside for loop, please post the full script source code.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/841904/running-a-single-executable-with-sudo-adds-two-processes-in-process-list
